# Counting and joining two tables

Tags: mysql, join, count

**Eventhosts** – containing the three regular hosts and an "other" field (if someone is replacing them) **or edit: being a guest host** (in addition to the regulars)

```
eventid | host (SET[Steve,Tim,Brian,other])
-------------------------------------------
      1 | Steve
      2 | Tim
      3 | Brian
      4 | Brian
      5 | other
      6 | other
```

**Event**

```
id | other | name etc.
----------------------
1  |       | …
2  |       | …
3  |       | …
4  | Billy | …
5  | Billy | …
6  | Irwin | …
```

This query:

```
SELECT h.host, COUNT(*) AS hostcount
FROM host AS h
LEFT OUTER JOIN event AS e ON h.eventid = e.id
GROUP BY h.host
```

Returns:

```
Steve | 1
Tim   | 1
Brian | 2
other | 2
```

I want it to return:

```
Steve | 1
Tim   | 1
Brian | 2
Billy | 1
Irwin | 1
```

OR:

```
Steve |       | 1
Tim   |       | 1
Brian |       | 2
other | Billy | 1
other | Irwin | 1
```

And **not**:

```
Steve |       | 1
Tim   |       | 1
Brian |       | 1
Brian | Billy | 1
other | Billy | 1
other | Irwin | 1
```

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this or point me in a direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT IF(h.host != 'other', h.host, e.other) as the_host, COUNT(e.*) AS hostcount
FROM host h
LEFT JOIN event e ON h.eventid = e.id
GROUP BY the_host
```

Just a note, don't use `COUNT(*)`, if a host don't have event, it will show 1 instead of 0. Use `COUNT(e.*)`

For the last result, use this:

```
SELECT h.host, e.other, COUNT(e.*) AS hostcount
FROM host h
LEFT JOIN event e ON h.eventid = e.id
GROUP BY IF(h.host != 'other', h.host, e.other),
   h.host, e.other -- try repeating it here
```

**[EDIT]**

Tried the following query(i.e. without the suggested repetition of fields on GROUP BY), it also works on your original question and your edited question.  I just installed MySQL now, I don't know if it has bearing on database type, I only enabled InnoDB and strict settings. By the way `COUNT(e.*)` (which is ANSI SQL-accepted I presume) doesn't work on MySQL, instead must use `COUNT(e.id)` (or maybe you already amended in your query):

```
SELECT h.host, e.other, COUNT(e.id) AS hostcount
FROM host h
LEFT JOIN event e ON h.eventid = e.id
GROUP BY IF(h.host != 'other', h.host, e.other)
   -- note: i removed the suggested repeating of fields here, it works on my box here.     
   -- Settings: InnoDB and strict mode
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns only the first "other" host, not the second.

Comment: hmm.. it doesn't return Irwin? interesting. what are the output of my query?

Comment: Well my example here is a simplified version of my DB which is pretty much identical. And translated it returns: Steve, 11; Tim, 11; Brian, 5; Billy, 2. (Where Billy should have had 1 and Irwin one as well.)

Comment: @Eikern: try repeating h.host and e.other in GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `GROUP BY` (since you don't want it collapsing values for that column) and add the `event.other` column to the column list.

```
SELECT h.host, e.other, COUNT(*) AS hostcount
    FROM host AS h
    LEFT OUTER JOIN event AS e ON h.eventid = e.id
```

I just remembered you could achieve the first solution as well by:

```
SELECT IF(h.host = 'other', e.other, h.host) AS host, COUNT(*) AS hostcount
    FROM host AS h
    LEFT OUTER JOIN event AS e ON h.eventid = e.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT eh.host, e.other, count(*)
FROM Eventhosts eh
LEFT JOIN Event e ON (eh.eventid = e.id)
GROUP BY eh.host, e.other
```

returns

```
Steve |       | 1
Tim   |       | 1
Brian |       | 1
other | Billy | 1
other | Irwin | 1
```